# What is the minimum permission set for a service account to export a table from a specific dataset on BigQuery to a specific bucket on CloudStorage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently I have a service account that can export anything from BigQuery to anywhere in cloud storage but I feel it has more permissions than meets Principle of Least Privilege.

What is the minimum permission set to run a BigQuery as a job, save that query to temporary table, and export that to Cloud Storage?

I suspect the answer will involve some permissions from the following groups.

- bigquery.tables
- bigquery.jobs
- bigquery.datasets
- resourcemanager.projects # Seems to be replacement for storage.buckets and storage.objects ?

Answer (score 0):

You could run some tests on a service account key for this one.

As you can see in [BigQuery IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#overview), if you add the roles [dataEditor](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.dataEditor) and [jobUser](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser) it might be quite enough for what you want. You could also test the [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) but this is still a `alpha` tool.

For [Cloud Storage IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-reference), maybe [roles/storage.objectCreator](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) would already be enough.

If you end up playing around with these roles and find which one works best I'd also recommend answering your own question with your findings so people arriving here by Google might learn how you did it.